# Detailsview does not display

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a master-detail view. In the gridview I have a button

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="btnViewDetails" runat="server" text="Edit" CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("BoundFieldId") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
```

Now in the RowCommand, I did

```
 DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Edit);
    if (e.CommandName.Equals("Select"))
        {
            var value = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);
            using (var dataContext = new xxxDataContext(Config.xxxConnectionString))
            {
                var dataList = (from t in dataContext.tableName
                                where te.Id == Convert.ToInt32(value)
                                select t).ToList();
                DetailsView1.DataSource = dataList;
                DetailsView1.DataBind();

            }
```

But I can't see my details view and it doesn't bind I guess. Why is this?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in the row command to see if everything get's executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested your approach and everything seems to be fine. I guess the things to check would be:

1) Check that there is actually data with that ID in the database

2) Ensure your GridView has the "onrowcommand" event wired-up in the source view - should look something like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" onrowcommand="GridView1_RowCommand">
```

Can you place a breakpoint inside the onrowcommand handler?

Comment: Hi Thanks both of you for the response.,Yes it fires the event and dataList returns the exact number of rows that of in the db.

Comment: Also  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand">

Comment: Very strange. Do you have any code in the page's PreRender event that might be causing it to re-bind? Put a breakpoint around everything that touches the DetailsView. Failing that, I would take a step back and create a blank page with a GridView, DetailsView and some dummy data and see if I can get a really basic example working, then gradually add complexity.